# Cakephp Career Database Design

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design

I am new in cakephp, I want to develop a simple career website, I have design the database, but i would like to show it to professionals and know if the structure is ok

Jobs Table

- id
- job_title
- job_description
- job_location
- company_id
- closing_date

**Applied_jobs Table**

- job_id
- candidate_id
- company_id

**Candidate_table**

- id
- username
- password
- email
- first_name
- last_name
- cv

**Company_Table**

- id
- username
- password
- company_name
- email

Is this design ok?

Your advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been [cross-posted to DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101749/32747) and should be deleted from here now.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html). This should give you the understanding on how to name your database and models correctly, ready for use with CakePHP.